# T-SQL to XML - Can multiple values per attribute be listed on their own line?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I'm currently using T-SQL to convert some data into XML. I need to list the values of an attribute on their own line. For some reason the T-SQL to XML keeps concatenating the values together on the same line.

**Sample Code:**

```
SELECT
    'Fruits' AS [Attribute/@name],
    'Apple' AS [Attribute/Value],
    'Orange' AS [Attribute/Value],
    'Grape' AS [Attribute/Value]
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('CustomProduce'), TYPE
```

**Sample Result:**

```
<CustomProduce>
  <Attribute name="Fruits">
    <Value>AppleOrangeGrape</Value>
  </Attribute>
</CustomProduce>
```

**Desired Result:**

```
<CustomProduce>
  <Attribute name="Fruits">
    <Value>Apple</Value>
    <Value>Orange</Value>
    <Value>Grape</Value>
  </Attribute>
</CustomProduce>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (fairly absurd) way in-case no one knows a better solution:

```
SELECT
    'Fruits' AS [Attribute/@name],
    '' AS [Attribute],
    'Apple' AS [Attribute/Value],
    '' AS [Attribute],
    'Orange' AS [Attribute/Value],
    '' AS [Attribute],
    'Grape' AS [Attribute/Value]
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('CustomProduce'), TYPE
```

Comment: You're my hero. Don't let anyone tell you differently!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do this through a SELECT * FROM #Table where you may or may not have multiple values?