# Can multiple values per attribute be listed on their own line from a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I asked a very similar question previously however now I need the same results but with a different input.

**Sample Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    [@name] VARCHAR(200),
    [Value] VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp ([@name], [Value]) 
SELECT 'Fruit', 'Apple' UNION
SELECT 'Fruit', 'Orange' UNION
SELECT 'Fruit', 'Grape'
```

**Select Statement**

```
SELECT
    [@name],
    [Value]
FROM #Temp
FOR XML PATH ('Produce'), ROOT('ProduceMaster'), TYPE
```

**Result**

```
<ProduceMaster>
  <Produce name="Fruit">
    <Value>Apple</Value>
  </Produce>
  <Produce name="Fruit">
    <Value>Grape</Value>
  </Produce>
  <Produce name="Fruit">
    <Value>Orange</Value>
  </Produce>
</ProduceMaster>
```

**Desired Result**

```
<ProduceMaster>
  <Produce name="Fruit">
    <Value>Apple</Value>
    <Value>Grape</Value>
    <Value>Orange</Value>
  </Produce>
</ProduceMaster>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546233/t-sql-to-xml-can-multiple-values-per-attribute-be-listed-on-their-own-line

Comment: The other question was from me as well, however, it starts differently. This question is from a SELECT * FROM #Temp where you don't know if you're going to have a set number of values.

Comment: I was kidding..But without looking at the details if you have the same problem with different input you should be able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the confidence. I've tried a number of different solutions but I cannot get this to work correctly so I have asked the wonderful community here. We'll see what happens.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    [@name] VARCHAR(200),
    [Value] VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp ([@name], [Value]) 
SELECT 'Fruit', 'Apple' UNION
SELECT 'Fruit', 'Orange' UNION
SELECT 'Fruit', 'Grape' UNION
SELECT 'Building', 'house'


Select  [@Name],
(
SELECT    
    [Value]
FROM #Temp t2
where t2.[@Name] = t1.[@Name]
FOR XML  PATH (''), TYPE
) FROM #Temp t1 GROUP by [@Name]
FOR XML PATH ('Produce'), ROOT('ProduceMaster'), TYPE
```